# Prop not available in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How do I use redux to fire a actionCreator to get my initial data.
I need a place to get my initial data when the app loads.

I put it here but `actionNoteGetLatest` is not a prop yet.
Please can you help.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    // This is where the API would go to get the first data.
    // Get the notedata.
    this.props.actionNoteGetLatest();
  }
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// Redux
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
// TODO: Add middle ware
// import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

// Componenets
import PageHome from './components/pages/PageHome';
import PageOther from './components/pages/PageOther';

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import './styles/index.css';
import rootReducer from './Reducers/index';
import { actionNoteGetLatest } from './actions/noteActions';


// TODO: Turn redux devtools off for production
// const store = createStore(combineReducers({ noteReducer }), {}, applyMiddleware(createLogger()));
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  {},
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
);
/* eslint-enable */

class Main extends Component {
  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props);
  //   this.state = {
  //   };
  // }

  componentDidMount() {
    // This is where the API would go to get the first data.
    // Get the notedata.
    this.props.actionNoteGetLatest();

    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="Main">
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={PageHome} />
              <Route path="/other" component={PageOther} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

connect(null, { actionNoteGetLatest })(Main);

Main.propTypes = {
  actionNoteGetLatest: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

noteActions.js

```js
import actionTypes from '../constants/actionTypes';


export const actionNoteGetLatest = () => ({
  type: actionTypes.NOTE_GET_LATEST,
});
```

Comment: The prop should be available in `componentDidMount`

Comment: I don't see it, I just tested again.

Comment: Show us how you import your action creator.

Comment: I have updated the code above

Comment: I didn't import it. Did I?

Comment: I also added noteActions.js above, thanks for the help

Comment: You need to render the proper connected component (result from `connected` hoc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are rendering the initial `Main` component instead of the connected one. Update the line with the `connect` call to:

```
const MainWrapper = connect(null, { actionNoteGetLatest })(Main);
```

Then, use the `MainWrapper` component in your render:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MainWrapper />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

Check that currently you are rendering the `<Main/>` component without providing any prop.

Comment: const MainWrapper = connect(null, { actionNoteGetLatest })(Main);

Main.propTypes = {
  actionNoteGetLatest: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><MainWrapper /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();